# SQL read multiple tables and self join

Tags: sql, database

Been trying to learn SQL and am stuck on a problem I want to understand:

Given the following tables:

```
TABLE - Customer.movie_id
ID  MOVIE_ID
-------------
x   Spiderman     
y   Batman   
z   Avengers  

TABLE - Customer.game_id
ID  GAME_ID
-------------
A   COD     
C   HALO   
D   BATTLEFEILD
B   MINECRAFT  

TABLE - Customer.type_id
ID  TYPE_ID
-------------
ii   AGE     
jj   GENDER   
kk   INCOME  

TABLE - Customer.Info
ID  MOVIE_ID  GAME_ID   TYPE_ID   DATA
--------------------------------------------
1     x          A        ii       20
2     x          A        jj       F
3     x          C        kk       1000
4     y          C        ii       40
5     y          D        jj       M
6     y          C        kk       5000
7     z          B        ii       60
8     z          B        jj       F
9     z          C        kk       10000
```

Produce an output that will show rows of AGE only if MOVIE_ID and GAME_ID match the same values on the GENDER type rows.

```
TABLE - Customer.Info

ID  MOVIE_ID  GAME_ID   TYPE_ID   DATA
--------------------------------------------
1     x          A        ii       20
7     z          B        ii       60
```

I have been able to do queries individually in python and process it there, but I don't have any idea of how to combine all of this into one query.

Can anyone help?

Comment: so you want to return the ages of the females regardless of income?

Comment: Not entirely. The example above's male age would be included if GAME_ID for it was C.

Comment: so you want the age rows where there is a gender row, regardless of gender?

Comment: I want age rows only when the rows with gender have matching game and movie ids. 

You need to read gender rows first, extract their game and movie ids then use that to find which age rows have a match of those items.

Comment: Same as what? Any pairs?

Comment: Please elaborate? I am looking for matching pairs based on the Gender rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the shortest. If any other rows exists that has the same ids and gender then return it:

```
select i1.*
from Customer.Info i1 inner join Customer.Info i2
    on      i2.MOVIE_ID = i1.MOVIE_ID and i2.GAME_ID = i3.GAME_ID
        and i1.TYPE_ID = 'ii' and i2.TYPE_ID = 'jj'
where and exists (
    select 1 from Customer.Info i3
    where i3.ID <> i2.ID
        and i3.MOVIE_ID = i2.MOVIE_ID and i3.GAME_ID = i2.GAME_ID
        and i3.TYPE_ID = 'jj' and i3.DATA = i2.DATA
);
```

I don't know if you intend for groups of more than two to all match together  without variation.

Comment: I did like your previous answer as well. Can I ask what improvements you see in your updated version?

Comment: I don't think the others were going to work. For this last round I had to add in the inner join so we'd have a handle on the gender to value to search for in the subquery. As for the prior one with grouping, that was going to collapse the matching rows into a single row.

Comment: Now that I look back closely at your desired output I think I'm not sure of the matching criteria again.

Comment: I believe I got the correct output from your previous example minus the grouping and the check for 'F'.  Thanks for helping! I am still going to learn your new one to see if it is better as you said.

Answer (score 0):

This data model is not normalized properly and everything is named poorly, but aside from that, you probably want some form of EXISTS clause, such as:

```
select
    i.*
from
    customer.info i
    join
    customer.type_id ti on ti.id = i.type_id
where
    ti.type_id = 'AGE'
    and
    exists(
        select 1
        from customer.info i2
        join customer.type_id ti2 on ti2.id = i2.type_id
        where i2.movie_id = i.movie_id
        and i2.game_id = i.game_id
        and ti2.type_id = 'GENDER'
    )
/
```

Or, if EXISTS is not available, you can do it joining two subqueries:

```
select 
    age_info.*
from
    (
        select i.*
        from customer.info i
        join customer.type_id ti on ti.id = i.type_id
        where ti.type_id = 'AGE'
    ) age_info
    join
    (
        select distinct i.movie_id, i.game_id
        from customer.info i
        join customer.type_id ti on ti.id = i.type_id
        where ti.type_id = 'GENDER'
    ) gender_info
    on gender_info.movie_id = age_info.movie_id
    and gender_info.game_id = age_info.game_id
/
```